# OpenJPA Configuration for container-managed connection to MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, openjpa

I have the following config for **persistence.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
   version="2.0">
   <persistence-unit name="pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
      <description>Persistent Unit for Entity Classes</description>
      <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
      <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/mydb</non-jta-data-source>
      <class>com.example.entity.BookEntity</class>
   </persistence-unit>    
</persistence>
```

And the following container-managed config for **home.xml** file (saved under ..\tomcat\conf\catalina\localhost directory):

```
<Context path="/home" antiJARLocking="true" reloadable="true">
<Resource name="jdbc/mydb" auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true"
    username="user"
    password="password"
    maxActive="10"
    maxIdle="5"
    maxWait="10000"
    removeAbandoned="true"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
    logAbandoned="true" />
</Context>
```

I have tried connecting to the database directly with MySQL Workbench and it works, but I don't know why I am not able to connect via contextual configuration.

I'm running the app on Tomcat 7 with JSF 2.

Why can't I connect with the above configurations? If required, I can post codes for the entity, ejb and controller. Please help, been stuck on this for the last three days...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas, Tomcat 7 does not support EJB 3 without a lot of mucking about to get it to work. I have moved my project to Glassfish version 3.1.